# National Capital Outflow Question

Tags: supply-and-demand, exchange-rates

I have the following example for an imposed quota on the importing of Japanese cars to Europe and it's relative effects:

[image]

I am told that $NX=NCO$ (Net exports are equal to National Capital Outflow). I understand we would see a shift to the right in the demand for Euros as relatively Imports have increased compared to Exports, but would we also see a shift in the NCO curve too as the purchase of foreign assets by domestic residents has decreased hence reducing the value of NCO?